# Role does not exist and unable to create database when using PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am using Heroku for my application and it requires PostgreSQL but you can still use SQLite3 for development. Since Heroku strongly advised against having 2 different databases I decided to change to PostgreSQL for development. I installed the `gem pg` and also went to the official PostgreSQL site to get the Windows installer and also changed my `database.yml`. During installation it requires a password for PostgreSQL so I made one. 
I had to change the `pg_hba.conf` file from using `md5` to `trust` in order get past: `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` when trying to create the database.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust # was md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust # was md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

After getting rid of that though, I now get this:

```
$ rake db:create
(in C:/app)
FATAL:  role "User" does not exist 
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"utf8", 
"database"=>"app_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>nil, "password"=>nil}
```

I do still have my `development.sqlite3` and `text.sqlite3` present, could that be the issue? What must be done?

Here is my full gist: https://gist.github.com/1522188

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Add a username to your `database.yml`, might as well use your application's name (or some variant of the name) as the username, I'll use `app_name` as a placeholder:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: app_name
  password:
```

Then create the user (AKA "role") inside PostgreSQL using `psql.exe`:

```
$ psql -d postgres
postgres=# create role app_name login createdb;
postgres=# \q
```

The first line is in your terminal, the next two are inside `psql`. Then do your `rake db:create`.

The `User` user is possibly a default but [`user` is already taken](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html) for other purposes in PostgreSQL so you'd have to quote it to preserve the case if you wanted to use `User` as a username:

```
postgres=# create role "User" login createdb;
```

You're better off creating one user per-application anyway.

You'll want to do similar things for your `test` entry in `database.yml` as well.

Comment: Its not letting me get inside of `psql.exe`. When I try to open it, the window comes up and then automatically closes so I then tried to go to the cmd prompt and typed in `c:\Program Files..\..\bin > psql.exe > psql: FATAL: role "User" does not exist` getting the `FATAL` once again. Any ideas?

Comment: @wrbg: You created a `postgres` user during installation, right? Try `psql -d postgres -U postgres`, if you need a password then `psql -d postgres -U postgres -W`.

Comment: It didn't prompt for a user during installation. Let me see in reinstalling.

Comment: OK, during installation it says my username is `postgres` if that helps you any. But other then that, yeah I just create a password, or in this case, enter the existing one.

Comment: @wrbg: Can you `psql -d postgres -U postgres`?

Comment: Ok so I created the role called `app` and now when I put in `rake db:create` I get `PGError: ERROR:  permission denied to create database`. Also your code above did work out.

Comment: @wrbg: Try `create role app_name login createdb` or `alter role app_name createdb` and then `rake db:create`. I probably had different defaults set up last time I did this.

Comment: So I ran inside of the `cmd prompt`: psql -d postgres -U postgres and then tried `create role app_name login createdb` and `alter role app_name createdb` but still no luck. How would I know if I even created my database?

Comment: @wrbg: You can use `\du` in `psql` to see the users/roles and their permissions or `\l` to list the databases. If your user is set up properly then `rake db:create` should create the database and `psql -U app_name -d app_development` should get into it.

Comment: Thank you for the help Mu, I was able to find out more about using the `pgAdminIII', starting the server by entering the password, seeing my new user and giving it permission to create databases. That solved the issue.

Comment: @Edward: Which command? [`create role`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html)?

Comment: @mu is too short, Can you please help me for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855405/postgresql-9-3-dynamic-pivot-table-for-huge-records

Answer (score 10):

PostgreSQL will try to create the database with your account (login) name if a `username` isn't specified in your `config/database.yml`. On OS X and Linux you can you see who this is with `whoami`. Looks like you're using Windows.

**Solution A:**
[Create a PostgreSQL user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html) that matches the one it's looking for. For example

```
createuser --superuser some_user
```

**Solution B:**
Change the DB user by explicitly setting a username [as shown in mu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8639649/72321).

Comment: Does it really need `--superuser` or is `-d` enough?

Answer (score 10):

If you have a specific account/user on your machine for postgres called postgres for example.

Then executing this command will bring a prompt for you to enter a role name.

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive
```

Then doing

```
rake db:create
```

Should work!