# Trying to migrate database for PostgreSQL, using Ubuntu, running into issues with "permissions" and "roles"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, database-migration

I recently installed Ubuntu and PostgreSQL. I'm trying to pull up my PostgreSQL database. If I type `rails db` I get this error

`psql: FATAL:  database "homed_in_development" does not exist`

So I then try running `rake db:create` or `rake db:migrate` but I get the error

`PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create database`

So I have tried `CREATE ROLE myusername;` after getting into PostgreSQL through the common `psql postgres`, which gives me the error `ERROR:  permission denied to create role`. I tried to fix this issue using `ALTER USER myusername WITH SUPERUSER`, but I got the error message `ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers`

I also got the error `FATAL: role “myusername” does not exist` on something else, and so I think my issues are that I haven't got roles or permissions set up properly.

Comment: I typed in `SELECT current_user;` to check what my current username is and it is the username that it says does not exist (`Role...myusername does not exist...`)

Comment: is this the first project you are using postgres? do you have previous project that you used `pg` in this machine?

Comment: @WaliAli I made the project on another machine and am now using this new machine.

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289366/postgres-no-permission-to-create-user) helps you

Comment: I was able to change the user's roles by first switching to the postgres user using `sudo -u postgres psql postgres` and then changing my other user under the postgres user using `ALTER USER maudulus WITH SUPERUSER;`

Comment: So it worked? good work!

Comment: @maudulus: You don't need sudo for that. You can `psql -U postgres...`. You might need other command-line options; you might need to type in the password for the user "postgres".