# Regarding the postgresql in rails application

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application I am using PG Gem database is created but when I try to run my server it gives the error that `role postgres does not exit`

That's my database file

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  username: postgres

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  password: password

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: app_test
  username: postgres

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  password: password
# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  #database: app_production
  #username: app
  #password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: app_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  username: postgres

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  password: password
```

when I try to run my application  it gives me that error

```
FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist
```

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: `CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN`.[`CREATE ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createrole.html)

Comment: can u tell how i create this

Comment: the command u tell is that rails console

Comment: Execute `CREATE ROLE postgres LOGIN` on your postgres server

Comment: actually i did not have knowlege about postgres so can u tell me how can i do this step by step

Comment: Do you have access to PostgreSQL DB ?,If so then just run that query in SQL console(_I dont know `Ruby On Rails`_)

Comment: no i have only these things which i mention

Comment: this may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639424/role-does-not-exist-and-unable-to-create-database-when-using-postgresql

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-postgresql-user-account/