# Can't convert DB from sqlite to postgres for rails app deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i have an app that i want to upload to Heroku. My plan has always been to use Heroku, but i forgot to develop the application based on Postgres. So now i want to launch the app, and i've been trying to follow the Heroku tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) to convert the Data Base to Postgres, but i'm getting this error after running "rake db:create" (as the tutorial tells you to do):

```
FATAL:  role "caiograco" não existe
```

"role "caiograco" não existe" means "role "caiograco" doesn't exist" in portuguese.

"caiograco" is  my linux user name, i dont know why it's appearing in this error.

But even before it, i was getting this other error message:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've been trying to get a solution by myself all day long now, but can't figure out whats going on.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This similar question may have information that could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639424/role-does-not-exist-and-unable-to-create-database-when-using-postgresql

Comment: are you running postgres locally?

Comment: Did you push your app to heroku `git push heroku` and migrate on heroku `heroku run rake db:migrate` or did you on your development machine?